# Using state change to trigger modal in React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-modal

I'm building a game in React Redux, and I have a condition where, upon being dealt cards, if the cards are over a certain amount I want a modal to put up so that the user can select one to discard.

Im doing this in the game logic by switching a part of the state called "cardHandOverflow" to true, and i want the modal to render on this condition. Im using React Modal library for this.

However im getting the error

```
react-dom.development.js:14997 Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

Here is the code im using:

```
export const CardHand: React.FC = () => {
  const cardHandOverflow = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.gameStateReducer.players.filter(player => player.id === Player.id)[0].cardHandOverflow);
  
  const [modalIsOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const closeModal = () => {
    setIsOpen(false)
  }

  if (cardHandOverflow) {
    setIsOpen(true)
  }

  return (
    <>
      {modalIsOpen ? 
        <DiscardModal 
          modalIsOpen={modalIsOpen} 
          closeModal={closeModal}
          discardableCards={cards}
        /> : null}
    </>
  )
```

Its obviously creating some sort of render loop with the useSelector and state change retriggering, however when i switch it out for a button the modal renders fine. How can i get the state change to render the modal once (so its acting like a click event)?

Many thanks :-)

Comment: The `if` statement should go in a `useEffect`, such as `useEffect(() => { if (cardHandOverflow) { setIsOpen(true); }}, [cardHandOverflow, setIsOpen])`.

Comment: @JacobSmit Thank you, that works. Id mark it as correct if it were an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by `setIsOpen(true);` when `cardHandOverflow` is truthy.

`setIsOpen` causes a rerender, even when the value does not change, and since it is directly part of your function component logic it will be run ever render while `cardHandOverflow` is true.

To avoid these loops you should make use of hooks provided by React, in this case `useEffect` is most appropriate.

```
export const CardHand: React.FC = () => {
    const cardHandOverflow = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.gameStateReducer.players.filter(player => player.id === Player.id)[0].cardHandOverflow);
    
    const [modalIsOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

    const closeModal = () => {
        setIsOpen(false)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (cardHandOverflow) {
            setIsOpen(true)
        }
    }, [cardHandOverflow, setIsOpen])

    return (
        <>
        {modalIsOpen ? 
            <DiscardModal 
            modalIsOpen={modalIsOpen} 
            closeModal={closeModal}
            discardableCards={cards}
            /> : null}
        </>
    )
}
```

The `useEffect` will only run the contained code on component mount and whenever a value in the dependency array `[cardHandOverflow, setIsOpen]` changes.